# How to set an equal image size for a Fallback Image as used for the Featured Image(dynamicly)

Tags: post-thumbnails

I have set a new size (width/height) for `Featured Image` and have also set the option to use a Default Image(Fallback image).

*The size used for the `Featured Image`: 1170/550 , the size for the Default Image is not set atm.*

My two questions are:

1. How can I set the (same) size as used for the `Featured Image` to my
   Default Image.
2. Is it possible to make the size for the Default Image dynamically, meaning by that:
    When changing the size for `Featured Image` the
   Default Image(my Fallback img) will then automatically use the size as set for the `Featured Image`.

The code I have/use right now:

```
<div class="post-thumbnail">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
    <?php 
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        the_post_thumbnail( 'featured-image' );
    } else {
        ?>
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/thumb_featured_img.jpg" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
        <?php
    } ?>
</a>
</div>
```

The code used for the `Featured Image`:

`add_image_size( 'featured-image', 1170, 550, array( 'center', 'center' ) );`

Is there a way to achieve this, and if so, how?

Comment: you mean to say  that your default image i.e thumb_featured_img.jpg    should be of 1170*550???

Comment: yes exactly but be dynamic (same as featured-image size ) not hard coded

Comment: rephrase question? is really confusing what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I have set featured image size to 1170*550 and have fallback image without any image size defined now I want the fallback image should have the same size as the featured image i.e. 1170*550, but it should be dynamic if featured image is reset then the fallback image should adjust accordingly

Comment: you are using the images directory inside your themes folder to pull the featured image in case featured image doesn't exit. Won't it be better to put the image of size 1170*550  in the images folder i.e to be used for the featured image.

Comment: actually I have set an option to set fallback image for users at the admin panle

Answer (score 0):

You can get the width and height of the image size set back from the global `$_wp_additional_image_sizes` array via the image size slug, so that:

```
global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;
$size = 'featured-image';
$width  = $_wp_additional_image_sizes[$size]['width'];
$height = $_wp_additional_image_sizes[$size]['height'];
```

Then in your template just change the image attributes:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); >/images/thumb_featured_img.jpg" width="<?php echo $width; ?>" height="<?php echo $height; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
```

Comment: more info  with examples: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_intermediate_image_sizes

Comment: Thanks for the comment but its not working 
actually my question may not be very clear add_image_size() actually crops the image I want some type of coping not re-sizing

Comment: @majick, and how should this help/answer the OP question?

Comment: he says he wants the fallback image to adjust according to the size of the featured image which may change, and this does exactly that. the display output of a single static fallback image is adjusted to match the featured image size if no featured image exists... if something else is being asked for I really can't see what.